# Proper way to install Eureka ImageRow using cocoapods in Swift 4

Tags: cocoapods, swift4, eureka-forms, xlform

I want to install Eureka with ImageRow for my Xcode project using cocoapods.

I am using Swift4 and after

```
  pod 'Eureka', '~> 3.0’
  pod 'ImageRow', '~> 2.0'
```

I get project that can't be compiled due to errors.

I found way to install only Eureka for swift 4 using

```
pod 'Eureka', :git => 'https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka.git', :commit => 'a238bbd'
```

But in this case I can't install ImageRow because it says

```
- `Eureka (from `https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka.git`, commit `a238bbd`)` required by `Podfile`
- `Eureka (= 3.0)` required by `ImageRow (2.0.0)`
```

p.s.
Now as Swift 4 finally released with Xcode 9 I am little confused that so popular library as Eureka can't be easily installed

Comment: I think you need Eureka version 4

Comment: Is it available?

Comment: Should be the last time I checked.